# SQL Query for getting the difference between a value from one row with a value another row

Tags: t-sql

I have data as shown in the table below

|ItemNo|  Date  |Value|  
 
--------------------------  
|  101 | 201002 |  5  |  
|  102 | 201002 |  3  |  
|  201 | 201002 |  7  |  
|  202 | 201002 |  2  |

|  101 | 201003 |  6  |  
|  102 | 201003 |  3  |  
|  201 | 201003 |  7  |  
|  202 | 201003 |  1  |

Result Expected  
|ItemNo|  Date  |Value|  
--------------------------
|  100 | 201002 |  2  |  
|  200 | 201002 |  5  |  
|  100 | 201003 |  3  |  
|  200 | 201003 |  6  |

Sorry for the format. I have reformatted it now. I am trying to get the difference in Value between Item No 101 and 102 for the Date 201002.
Is this possible to get. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reformat that with the code tags so it is readable?

Comment: OK now that it's readable, can you explain what function you want to run?  Are you subtracting the 102 from 101 and 202 from 201?

Comment: Do you want to club two rows, and result one row which will be difference of two rows?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT
    T1.ItemNo - 1 AS ItemNo,
    T1.Date,
    T1.Value - T2.Value AS Value
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table1 T2
ON T1.Date = T2.Date
AND T1.ItemNo + 1 = T2.ItemNo
```

Comment: Minor edit - Should be "t1.value - t2.value as value" - the subtraction was the wrong way around.